# AJAX and server security using http access-control-allow-*

Tags: javascript, ajax, security

I'm working on a JavaScript library and I would like anybody using it can make request to my server.
Because this I have added the access-control-allow-origin,method headers to my server responses.

Thigs works fine but my is question is: Is that secure for my server? there is any other implication I can take into account?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's as secure as the code on your server is. If you allow people to send an AJAX request that can drop a table, then no it's not secure. But if you follow best practices for website/scripting security it should be as safe as handling any other request your server normally would.

Answer (score 0):

Can anonymous users make changes to your server (e.g. incrementing a vote counter, post a comment, delete a post, etc)? If so, does it matter if a website you don't control makes some or all of their users make use of this feature of your site? Do the access control headers allow remote XHR to make those requests? If so, you have a problem.

Can known users make changes to your server? If so, does it matter if a website you don't control makes some or all of their users who are also your users make use of this feature of your site? Do the access control headers allow remote XHR to make those requests? Do the access control headers allow authentication methods (such as cookies) through? If so, you have a problem.

In short:

- Can a user do something potentially undesirable on your site?
- Do your access-control headers prevent third party websites from making users do those undesirable things?